# Is there a possibility to tell the gcc compiler to ignore function attributes? Or to speed up compilation time?

Tags: c, gcc

I don't have much experience with C and am now working on a HPC project which very often uses `__attribute__ ((always_inline)) void foo()` function definitions.
I see the point of doing it for performance runs, but for debugging, testing, and developing, the compilation time is way to long. Just earlier I wanted to add a simple `printf` in a function to see when the function is called, and had to wait 5min for it to compile.

Is there a possibility to pass `gcc` a flag to ignore the attribute requests? I already am compiling with the lowest level of optimization.

Comment: Have you done any testing to see if this actually has any noticeable impact on compilation time?

Comment: An Inline Function is As Fast As a Macro! https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Comment: in times past, it used to take over night (or at least hours) for even a very simple program to compile.   However, in today's world, 5 minute compile time strongly indicates that the code is very poorly written (as in no localization of functionality, using multiple separate files, etc)  and that the person initiating the compile has not taken advantage of the `make` utility to avoid (re)compiling code that has not changed

Comment: The proper way to speed up compile time is to arrange the code into separate files, use the `make` utility so unchanged files are not recompiled.

Answer (score 2):

A hackish way of disabling the attribute might be to define it away in the preprocessor:

```
#define always_inline noinline
```

A better approach, however, would be to apply those attributes in a macro so that they can be configured globally, e.g.

```
#ifndef DEBUG
# define HOT_FUNCTION __attribute__ ((always_inline))
#else
# define HOT_FUNCTION /* nothing */
#endif
…
HOT_FUNCTION void foo() { … }
```